# Will there be any error if h file includes signature which has no c file implementation?

Tags: c

Should there be any errors, if a `.h` file contains a signature, which has no implementation in a `.c` file?

Comment: Why should there be any error unless you were to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the function, and it isn't implemented, you will get a link error.  Otherwise, no errors or warnings will occur.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not an error to declare a function and not define it.

If you enable warnings, you may get a warning if you define a function with `static` linkage that does not get used in this translation unit.